# Combining two studies of different types

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, observational-study, random-allocation

**Initial Setup**

In a specific experimental design, there are two treatments and two study sites. Suppose we have the model
\begin{align*}
Y_{ijk} = \beta^\intercal X_{ijk} + \mu_i + \nu_j + \eta_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}
\end{align*}
where $Y_{ijk}$ is the outcome for the $i$th cluster ($i = 0, 1$), $j$ treatment ($j = 0, 1)$, and $k$th individual $(k=1, \cdots, n)$, $X_{ijk}$ are baseline covariates, and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ are i.i.d with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. For identifiability, we assume $\eta_{00} = \eta_{10} = \eta_{01}$. Letting $\mu_{ij} = E[Y_{ijk}]$, note that
\begin{align*}
TE_1 - TE_0 = (\mu_{11} - \mu_{10}) + (\mu_{01} - \mu_{00}) = \eta_{11} + \beta^\intercal (E[X_{11k}] - E[X_{10k}] + E[X_{01k}] - E[X_{00k}])
\end{align*}
**If both sides were randomized**, then $E[X_{11k}]  = E[X_{10k}]$ and $E[X_{01k}] = E[X_{00k}]$ since covariates are balanced in probability. So, $\eta_{11}$ is a measure of treatment-site interaction; that is, if the treatment effect is modified by site. This is the parameter we would like to test in $H_0: \eta_{11} = 0$ vs $H_1: \eta_{11}\neq 0$.

**The Wrinkle**

Site 1 is randomized, but Site 2 is not. How would one approach to combine observations for both sites, and appropriately adjust sample size calculations (say, with size 0.05 and power 0.80) to reject $H_0$?